# Ask for input until input is 0

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    if (i=== 0) {break;}
  arr.push(prompt('Enter a number ' + (i+1)));
}

document.write('Output: ' + arr.reverse(', '));
```

I am trying to create a prompt that keeps asking for a number until the input is a 0, after the input is 0, the numbers will be displayed backwards, I have tried the above but it's not working, what am I doing wrong?

```
var arr = [];

    while(true){
      var x = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number ' + (i+1)));
      if (x === 0 ) { break;}
      arr.push(x);
   }

document.write('Output: ' + arr.reverse(', '));
```

Comment: `but it's not working` ... what isn't working?

Comment: I think it might have to do something with `var i = 0` and `if (i === 0) {break;}` ;). Have you heard of a while loop?

Comment: Yes I have heard of it and I tried to implement it but I didn't know how I could call the prompt value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are breaking your loop at the very beginning

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    if (i=== 0) {break;}
      // The following code is not accesible as you are breaking when your i is 0
       arr.push(prompt('Enter a number ' + (i+1)));
     }
```

You may want to store the value you get in a variable and check whether you got 0 or not to terminate the loop. Like following

```
    for(var i =0;i < 99;i++){
      var x = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number ' + (i+1)));
      if (x === 0 ) { break;}
      arr.push(x);
   }
```

Try the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ntvy8fyo/1/)

Comment: I am not getting any prompt using the code you provided

Comment: Probably you are making mistake somewhere else. Can you post your updated code?

Comment: I have put it under my question

Answer (score 0):

For your original attempt, modify ;

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; true ; i++) {
     arr.push(prompt('Enter a number ' + (i+1)));
    if (arr[i] === "0") {break;}

}

document.write('Output: ' + arr.reverse(', '));
```